# Google App Engine query filter by date

Tags: java, google-app-engine, parsing

How exactly does GAE filter query results by date?

I'm trying to pass a datestamp through the query but I can't get it to work.

In the Google Dashboard Datastore viewer the date field is stored as a gd:when type with the format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS but when displayed on a webpage displays as Mon Jul 15 20:15:35 UTC 2013.

I request the string Mon Jul 15 20:15:35 UTC 2013 from a jsp page and parse it but the filter isn't working.

```
    String strDatestamp = req.getParameter("stamp");
    String FormatString = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
    Date datestamp = null;
    try {
        datestamp = new SimpleDateFormat(FormatString).parse(strDatestamp);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Filter filter = new FilterPredicate
                           ("date", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, datestamp);
    Query query = new Query("Example", key).setFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date in computer systems is actually represented as time, in particular case it's internally represented as [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds. See for yourself: [`date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29).

What you see is only human-readable representation, which lacks full millisecond precision.

To query for a particular second you will need to query for a particular time range within one second. So you will need to do range query between `Mon Jul 15 20:15:35 UTC 2013` and `Mon Jul 15 20:15:36 UTC 2013` (note the second change):

```
Filter startFilter = new FilterPredicate("date", Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, startSecond);
Filter endFilter = new FilterPredicate("date", Query.FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, nextSecond);
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't work anymore in the current version.